# How do I use pdo execute function to select table?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

**index.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';
DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM users");
```

In this class i am using singleton pattern it is successfully connected with db.

**DB.php**

```
<?php
class DB{

private static $_instance = null;
private $_pdo, $_query, $_error = false, $results, $count = 0;    
private function __construct(){
  try{
 $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.Config::get('mysql/host') .';db='.Config::get('mysql/db'),Config::get('mysql/username'),Config::get('mysql/password'));
     //echo "Connected";
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

}
public static function getInstance(){

     if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
         self::$_instance = new DB();
     }
     return self::$_instance;
}

public function query($sql){
    $this->_error = false;

    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){
     //  echo 'prepared statement';

       if($this->_query->execute()){
         echo 'do query';
       }else{
         echo 'did not execute';
       }
    }
  }
 }
```

Now the problem is when i pass sql query in `query()` it falls in else condition 'did not execute'. so my question why it does not execute. is there any compatibility problems in pdo with mysql db or i am doing somthing wrong.

Comment: Have you taken a closer look on here? https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/select  or here, https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: I would recommend starting by making a working example without wrapping it in a class first. You should also read up on how to check for errors when making queries. TBH, I would rather recommend using a tried and tested db-library instead of building your own.

Comment: You should use an already existing wrapper class instead of creating your own. You could use my class, [GrumpyPDO](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/GrumpyPDO) (which I obviously personally recommend), but there are [dozens](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper) [if](https://github.com/paragonie/easydb) [not](https://www.imavex.com/php-pdo-wrapper-class/) [hundreds](https://github.com/jlake/EasyPDO) more that are similar. There really isn't an need to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 1):

I always enable PDO exceptions. If a problem occurs with a query, or any other call to PDO functions, it will throw an exception that includes an error message.

```
$this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

(You only need to set this once, typically right after you create the PDO connection.)

See http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

If you don't want to use exceptions, you should check for errors after *every* call to `query()` or `prepare()` or `execute()`, and output them to the error log.

```
$this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql);
if ($this->_query === false) {
   $this->_error = $this->_pdo->errorInfo();
   error_log("Error '{$this->_error[2]}' when preparing SQL: {$sql}");
   return false;
}
$ok = $this->_query->execute();
if ($ok === false) {
   $this->_error = $this->_query->errorInfo();
   error_log("Error '{$this->_error[2]}' when executing SQL: {$sql}");
   return false;
}
```

Comment: I think `$ok = $this->_query->execute;` is not returning boolean logic.your 2nd `if` is not getting false and it is not showing error logs.

Comment: even i remove my `try-catch` block in construcutor

Comment: [**PDOStatement::execute** Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)